# beautiful soup extracting exact td tags

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to get started with BS4, but I seem to have hit some trouble with one of these tables. So, I have something like the following:

```
<td align="center" valign="top">
foo
</td>
<td align="center">
foo bar
</td>
<td align="center" class="new" valign="top">bar</td>
<td align="center" class="newq" valign="top">foo</td>
```

and I would like to extract just the `<td align="center">` from the above. So, I have something like:

```
td_al_center = soup.find_all('td',{'align':'center'})
```

but this gives me all 4 above combinations. How do I specify only to extract the `<td align="center">` (the one with `foo bar`)? Would greatly appreciate if anyone could put me on the right track..

Comment: try with `soup.find_all('td',{'class':'new'})`

Comment: @SivaCn: Why? That obviously won't return the one he wants.

Comment: @abarnert It'works fine (Python2.7) `soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'new'})`, it'a bad idea that, by filtering with the common parameters such as `align="center"` since there may be several tags associated with it.

Comment: @SivaCn: No it doesn't. He wants to find the second tag, the one with "foo bar". You're finding the third tag, the one with "bar". And there's no obvious way to adapt what you're doing to find what he wants—in fact, that's exactly what he's asking how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't search for all the tags that have only exactly the attributes you specify… but you *can* search for tags that don't have a specific attribute, by specifying `None` as a value for it. So:

```
>>> td_al_center = soup.find_all('td', {'align': 'center', 'valign': None})
>>> td_al_center
[<td align="center">
foo bar
</td>]
```

Comment: Awesome - this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a tonne for this. Wasted 2 hours searching how to do this!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your criteria is that the element a) must have `align="center"` and b) cannot have any other attributes, it looks to me like you'll have to use a function as your filter.

```
def centered_only(tag):
    return len(tag.attrs) == 1 and tag.attrs.get('align') == 'center'

td_al_center = soup.td(centered_only)
```

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function for the details on functions as filters.

As you've seen, it's easy to filter on the value of specific attributes, but I don't see anything in `find_all` or the tag name shorthand that can enforce the absence of all other attributes besides the functional filter.

Comment: This isn't necessary in this particular case, but it's the most general solution to the question and all related questions.